# wp-admin/index.php gives a "500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, linux

experts,

UPDATE:

hello dear experts

**UPDATE.** many many thanks for the great ideas and tipps. overwhelming - really your are overwhelming!!!

i have done as adviced and this method made it clear. i created a folder which i called plugins-deactivated... into this folder i copied / or let me say moved all the modules

a the end i had left an empty folder called wp-plugins:-) 
and now i was able to login and see the dashboad... ;<)
some / one of the following ones sure cauese the troubles...

```
The plugin amazon-einzeltitelv1.2/amazon-einzeltitellinksv1.2.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.
The plugin amazon-link/amazon.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.
The plugin amazon-product-in-a-post-plugin/amazon-product-in-a-post.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.
The plugin amazon-scraper/amazon-plugin.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.
The plugin amazonsimpleadmin/amazonsimpleadmin.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.
http://literaturen.org/wp-admin/plugins.php
```

end of update:

afters installation and a few configuration-tasks i cannot login any more;

http://www.my-page.org/wp-login.php - this can be reached

http://www.my-page.org/wp-admin/ - this only shows a blank page

well - what happened,

/wp-admin/install.php works as it should.
/wp-admin/index.php gives a "500 Internal Server Error"

i ve checked permissions and ownership.

I seem to be able to access .css files and images located inside the /wp-admin 
folder with no problem, but the index.php file causes a 500 error.

Comment: Create a folder within your WordPress installations wp_content/plugins folder called 'plugins_deactivated'. Then move all your plugin files and folders into that folder you just created. All you should now see in wp_content/plugins, is the folder you created. Now try login again. If you are able to without getting 500 internal server error, it is one of your plugins. try moving them back and activating them again one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: You need to retreive the error message. It's hard to guess without it. Please have a look in your `error.log` or tell PHP to display the errors directly and not just print out a white page using `ini_set('display_errors', true);` in `/wp-admin/index.php`

Comment: hello you both -first of all - many many thanks for the hints. added a folder and put all the plugin-stuff to it. untill the plugin-folder was empty. so i am glad i was able to login finally... now i will look whih one is the culprit - again many thanks